# Uninstalling OpenCV on Ubuntu

Tags: opencv, user-interface, uninstallation

Sorry, I read all previous questions, but no solution worked for me.

I have downloaded and installed the OpenCv library 3.1.0 (long time ago)
Yesterday, I went into samples/python but I could not run: 
python gabor_threads.py icub.jpg

ERROR: cv2.imshow(‘img’, img)
If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage

Searching for similar error, I understood that I had to remove the current installation of Opencv and build a new one with GUI support.

Inside the opencv dir I run:

```
sudo apt-get purge libopencv*
sudo apt autoremove
```

I removed a lot of pck BUT

```
sudo make uninstall
```

Failed. 
Also

```
sudo pip uninstall opencv
```

failed

I do not remember how did I install it (with pip, make, …)

What can I do now? I guess I have to completely remove OpenCV, but I do not know how to do it.

Btw: after openCV I installed keras with conda.

Thank you so much.
Idil

Below is a copy-paste of my opencv dir (I do not have the build dir):

```
idil@toshiba:~/Downloads/opencv-3.1.0$ ls
3rdparty                 CTestTestfile.cmake  opencv2
apps                     custom_hal.hpp       OpenCVConfig.cmake
bin                      cvconfig.h           OpenCVConfig-version.cmake
cmake                    data                 OpenCVModules.cmake
CMakeCache.txt           doc                  platforms
CMakeFiles               Ele_Read_me.odt      README.md
cmake_install.cmake      include              release
CMakeLists.txt           junk                 samples
cmake_uninstall.cmake    lib                  test-reports
CONTRIBUTING.md          LICENSE              unix-install
CPackConfig.cmake        Makefile             version_string.tmp
CPackSourceConfig.cmake  modules
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem: I had to go inside the "release" subdir to type

```
sudo make uninstall
```

I remembered that I did installed OpenCV following the instruction @https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

Regards, Idil